# Value not set error in Scalate/Jade

Tags: scalatra, scalate

I am new to Jade and Scalate. I have the following route defined:

```
get("/") {
  jade("index",
    "pageTitle" -> "Welcome to Jade",
    "welcomeMessage" -> "Hello my pretties")
}
```

And the template:

```
-@ val pageTitle: String
-@ val welcomeMessage: String

!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
  body
    h1= welcomeMessage
```

The error I get on page render is:

```
The value for 'title' was not set
org.fusesource.scalate.NoValueSetException: The value for 'title' was not set
at org.fusesource.scalate.RenderContext$$anonfun$attribute$1.apply(RenderContext.scala:159)
```

Even if I remove the line `title= pageTitle` I still get the error. What is the error referring to and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't notice `default.scaml` in the layouts folder. It was defining, but not setting, `title`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a clean build with SBT as follows.

```
sbt clean clean-files
```

Note: You need to exit SBT first.

I had a similar value-not-set error for a different reason but this command helped me resolve the problem.